# EF 4.3: can't use Find and Where within the same context

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have code structure like that:

```
var adjective = context.Adjectives.Find(11); //works
var substantive = context.Substantives.Find(11);  //works    
var address = context.Addresses.Where(v => v.ZipCode == new_possible_address.ZipCode).SingleOrDefault();  //works    

var name = context.Names.Find(91); //doesn't work
```

The last line shows the error message:

> "The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot
>   be modified."

I've noted if I remove the Where statment, the last Find method works. So:

```
var adjective = context.Adjectives.Find(11); //works
var substantive = context.Substantives.Find(11);  //works    

var name = context.Names.Find(91); //now works
```

Also, if I use the debug feature "Set Next Statement" going to adjective or substantive lines right after the execution of "Addresses.Where" line. Both methods stops working too.

Why I can't use Find and Where method within the same context?

Comment: Test on another computer, or format hard disk, reinstall OS, .NET, Visual Studio, EF, recompile solution... This error is just crazy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a model problem. I had to complete a navigation mapping like that:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<People>().HasOptional(c => c.Address).WithMany();
```

I needed just this way.